# itextsharp text extraction fails for some pdfs

Tags: itext

I have couple of PDF files whose text I am not able to extract from. These PDFs file were created by converting Word files to PDFs. 
The main purpose I am extracting text from pdf is to index its text and make it searchable.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFileName);
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    // where  strPDFText is string builder 
    strPDFText.Append(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page) + " ");
}                    
string str = strPDFText.ToString();
```

I get an empty string. What could be the reason for the same. I am using Itextsharp 5.5

Comment: Please share the PDFs in question.

Comment: Can you give me your emailId, I will forward it to Email ID.

Comment: Please look at my profile. That been said, to give more so participants the chance to inspect the files, it generally is preferred to share the file (e.g. Using public Dropbox or Google shares).

Comment: Here is sample pdf which has the problem.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QBm7z507k_MWU4QTFoM2M5b1U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

While the sample PDF provided by the OP indeed indicates that it is a MS Word export, it simply does not contain any text, only an image (which incidentally shows text).

The content of the PDF is this:

```
 /P <</MCID 0>> BDC BT
/F1 11.04 Tf
1 0 0 1 540.1 500.95 Tm
/GS7 gs
0 g
0 G
[( )] TJ
ET
 EMC  /P <</MCID 1>> BDC q
0.000000071 488.88 612 231.12 re
W* n
468 0 0 219.05 72 500.95 cm
/Image8 Do Q
 EMC
```

As you see the only actual text displayed is a single space (`[( )] TJ`), and the only remaining content is a bitmap image (`/Image8 Do`).

Thus,

> I get an empty string. What could be the reason for the same.

The reason is that there is no text in your document.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to extract text from these images?

Comment: You need OCR software to convert the pixels in the image to text characters.

Comment: @user3469808 As Bruno says, you need OCR software to do that. You can use iText, though, to retrieve the image file from the PDF to forward it to the OCR software.

Comment: Thanks, I will look for an OCR library. Are there any commercial\free OCR libraries which you would recommend?

Comment: I have not yet have to cope with OCR and, therefore, don't know the pros and cons of OCR libs. @BrunoLowagie, do you have an idea?

Comment: No, it's outside the scope of what I do.